# How to deal with large sparse data file (1 & 0) while inputing to AMPL

Tags: sparse-matrix, ampl

I have a an optimization model with a three dimensional parameter matrix with binary values. >50% of this matrix is 0. While reading the .dat file itself, my 4GB memory is getting used. Using a bigger RAM is not desirable. 
       param p_ijk{A,B,C};
How to deal with this. Is there a way to index the values with value 1 and input it to AMPL?

Comment: You need your data to be more sparse in order to have benefits for using a sparse model. In my opinion, the upper limit of ratio for non-zero values must be 10% in the worst case. Less is better.

Comment: @valentin Not necessarily. By using the default value you can get some memory savings even if there is little sparsity.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a default value of 0 when declaring parameter

```
param p_ijk{A,B,C} default 0;
```

and provide only nonzero values for it in the data. This way zeros won't be stored saving some memory.